# How to programmatically get the job id of a newly backgrounded process in Bash

Tags: bash, job-control

In Bash, how do you programmatically get the job id of a job started with `&`?

It is possible to start a job in the background with `&`, and then interact with it using its job id with Bash builtins like `fg`, `bg`, `kill`, etc.

For instance, if I start a job like

```bash
yes > /dev/null &
```

I can then kill it with the following command (assuming this job gets job id 1):

```bash
kill %1
```

When creating a new job with `&`, how do you programmatically get the job id of the newly created job?

---

I realize you can get the *process id* (not the job id) with `$!`, but I am specifically wondering about how you can get the job id.

Comment: Similar: [How to get the Job ID?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/110911)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `jobs` prints the currently running background jobs along with their ID:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do yes > /dev/null & done
[1] 3472564
[2] 3472565
[3] 3472566

$ jobs
[1]   Running                 yes > /dev/null &
[2]-  Running                 yes > /dev/null &
[3]+  Running                 yes > /dev/null &
```

So, to get the id of the last job launched that is still running, since [it will be marked with a `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18192497/1081936), you could do (with GNU `grep`):

```
$ jobs | grep -oP '\d(?=]\+)'
3
```

Or, more portably:

```
$ jobs | sed -n 's/^\[\([0-9]*\)\]+.*/\1/p'
```

However, note that if you suspend one of the jobs, then that will take the `+`. So you might want to just take the last line:

```
$ jobs | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '][+'
3
```

Comment: Also note that the last two will be marked with `-` and `+` making them even more easily separated out. (Or to be more precise the default jobs for interactions via `fg` etc. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192497))

Comment: The one marked with `+` is the one `fg` / `bg` will act on by default, they're not necessarily the one launched last. For instance, a job that has been suspended will be chosen over one that was started later but is still running. If a job terminates, the `+` will move to an earlier job.

Comment: Yes, @StéphaneChazelas I should have said "the most recently launched still running job". And I had never realized about the suspended jobs! As soon as you suspend a backgrounded job, the `+` is moved to it! So what does that mean? The `+` is the job that you most recently interacted with in any way?

Comment: It's the "current job", the job the shell thinks you'll likely want to resume. That all comes from BSD / csh where job control was initially implemented. See `info bash 'job control'` for details.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from the bash manual:

> There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell.  The character % introduces a job specification (jobspec).  Job number  n  may  be  referred to as %n.  A job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears in its command line.   For  example,  %ce  refers  to  a  stopped ce job.  If a prefix matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  Using %?ce,  on  the      other  hand,  refers to any job containing the string ce in its command  line.  If the substring matches more than one job, bash reports an  error.   **The symbols %% and %+ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in  the  foreground  or started  in  the  background.**  The previous job may be referenced using %-.  If there is only a single job, %+ and %- can both be used to refer  to  that  job.   In  output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous  job  with  a -.  **A single % (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job.**

Also, the command `jobs -l` lists the job IDs together with PIDs, which may allow you to translate the PID (obtained from `$!`) to a job ID using some script.

Answer (score 3):

Jobs numbers can be reused, process ids and process group ids can be reused, there's no guarantee that between you invoking `cmd &` and invoking `job`, the process running `cmd` will not have terminated.

In `bash`, the output of `jobs` is not post-processable anyway in general.

What you can rely on is that after

```
A | B | C &
```

And provided that you don't have `trap`s that start pipelines asynchronously, `$!` will contain the pid of the process that was started to run `C`.

Processes running `A`, `B` and `C` and their descendants if any will be in one job (in interactive shells where job control is enabled). The shell will have picked the first free job number. That job will have been made the current job (also referred to as `%+` (or `%%` or even `%` in some shells) in arguments to `kill`/`fg`/`bg`) only if there was no otherwise suspended job.

`jobs -l` in bash lists jobs along with the ids of the processes in them it knows about. It seems it even list the ones that are already terminated (listing the one running `true` as `Running` in my test of `sleep 100 | true` which looks like a bug), so you should be able to look for `$!` in there. Doing so reliably is impossible though.

You'd have more luck by using `zsh` and its `$jobstates` special associative array whose keys are job ids and values like `running:+:37632=running:37633=done`

```
job_id=${(k)jobstates[(R)*:$!=*]}
```

Here looking for elements whose value contains `:$!=`, bearing in mind that though unlikely, it's not impossible for two jobs to have processes with the same pid as pids can be reused after processes have terminated and their death have been acknowledged by their parent.

Now, once you have that `job_id`, you have to make sure that no other job is started in background or is suspended before you use it as that job_id could very well have been reused.

Instead of relying on job ids, you could insert unique strings in the job names and refer to them by `%?that-string`.

For instance:

```
sleep 100 | sleep 101 $(: first) &
sleep 123 | sleep 123 $(: second) &
kill '%?first'
```

Would kill the job with the processes running `sleep 100` and `sleep 101` if still running and if both are already dead by the time you run `kill`, you'll get a `kill: %?first: no such job` error.

Comment: Very clever solution. How does `$(: test)`work?

Comment: `:` is the no-op command, so `: first` does nothing let alone *output* anything, so `$(: something)` expands to nothing, but `something` does show up in the job table.